# Receiving boot complete without UI

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

My app does not have a UI.
I need to receive the boot_complete broadcast to perform certain setup actions.
I see that Android has a restriction preventing an app from receiving broadcasts unless it is launched by the user.
I was wondering if there is a way to get this to work.

Comment: "I see that Android has a restriction preventing an app from receiving broadcasts unless it is launched by the user" -- more accurately, it will not receive broadcasts until something uses an explicit `Intent` to interact with one of your components. For the vast majority of applications, that means having an activity that can be launched via the home screen. Apps that are plugins to some other app might be able to avoid this, if the plugin host will use an explicit `Intent` to interact with one of your components.

Comment: Easiest way is to add an "About" activity or a setting activity to your app and let the user launch it.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you very much Mark. The host App does not use an explicit intent. It binds to the plugin using aidl. The plugin has two background services. One service is responsible for all regular operations. The other service needs to be started on boot_complete so that it can setup the Alarms.

Comment: "It binds to the plugin using aidl" -- then the host has to be using an explicit `Intent`, on Android 5.0+, as binding using implicit `Intents` is no long supported.

Comment: Thanks Mark. In this case, I think I will switch to explicit intents and since I don't have any alarms to set up until the Host App binds with the plugin using an explicit intent, all should be fine.